# How to prevent GetSaveFileName from automatically highlighting the filename edit box

Tags: c++, winapi

In Windows 7, the GetSaveFileName dialog automatically highlights the filename edit box. It does it when the dialog initiates, when focus is lost and regained to the dialogbox and when the filename edit box is clicked on. Its really annoying. How do I disable it?

Comment: You can hook the dialog. However this would be bad practice, changing some UI that all other apps have.

Comment: I would find it very annoying if the dialog did *not* do give initial focus to the Edit control.  It means that I would have to click or tab on the Edit control before I could enter a filename.

Comment: Which part do you find annoying? The fact that the edit control gains focus, or that the edit control selects the entire contents when it gains focus? The latter [can be customized](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031114-00/?p=41823).

Comment: Using firefox I save image as. Save as dialog box. hoto.jpg appears in filename editbox. photo.jpg already exists so it asks do you want to overwite it? No -> reverts back to Save as dialog box. it has lost focus away from edit box to save button. So I click filename edit box. But in the process of focus being being changed to filename edit box. It has highlighted it again.When I refuse to overwrite an existing file, I want focus put back on the filename edit box without automatic highlighting and not have to click twice to remove that highlighting.

Comment: This maybe a potential issue, you could try to submit it to the feedback hub.

Comment: Update: When you click save button, the focus is on the button, after you refuse to overwrite an existing file, the focus put back on the save button, the first click is changing the focus to the edit control. the behavior is expected.

Answer (score -4):

If you look at comdlg32.dll (Windows 7 only) using W32dasm

```
:6F0683D3        push    FFFFFFFF
:6F0683D5        push    00000000
:6F0683D7        push    000000B1
:6F0683DC        add     ecx, FFFFFFA4
:6F0683DF        call    6F0569B8
:6F0683E4        push    eax
```

- Reference To: USER32.SendMessageW, Ord:027Ch

  :6F0683E5    call    dword ptr [6F051230]

You will immediately know that line 3 (push 000000B1)
is calling Sendmessage EM_SETSEL to the filename editbox.

winuser.h contains the id's of the messages.

```
#define EM_GETSEL               0x00B0
#define EM_SETSEL               0x00B1
#define EM_SETMARGINS           0x00D3
```

So if you use a hex editor to change B1 to D3 it won't
be calling EM_SETSEL anymore, but you do have to be
careful what message you're diverting it to.

You will have to create another Windows installion
on another drive to edit comdlg32.dll in the system32
folder, while that Windows installation isn't running.

That is a really annoying problem, you have to click on the filename edit box 3 times before it unhighlights and you can start using it.

Comment: Using a hex editor to modify one of the system DLLs (which clearly would affect every application, not just your own, as well as immediately being undone by botn Windows system file protection and any OS update) is not a reasonable solution to the question asked.